# Warning: is_readable(): open_basedir restriction in effect

Tags: magento-1.9, permissions, bug

since the last update of magento 1.9.4.1 i see a bug :

> Warning: is_readable(): open_basedir restriction in effect. 
>   File(/opt/php-7.2/lib/php//var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/magento_dev/var/log/system.log)
>   is not within the allowed path(s): (
>   /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web:
>   /var/www/clients/client1/web1/private:
>   /var/www/clients/client1/web1/tmp: /var/www/odyssee-vins.com/web:
>   /srv/www/odyssee-vins.com/web: /usr/share/php5: /usr/share/php: /tmp:
>   /usr/share/phpmyadmin: /etc/phpmyadmin: /var/lib/phpmyadmin)
>
> in /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/magento_dev/lib/Zend/Loader.php
>   on line 186

i don't understand why it's say that.
i delete manually the system.log and this msg appeared like he can't create the new file.

it's really strange, if you have any idea, i take them.

Comment: I have this issue too. It is related to the double forward slash in the path ...php//var.... Did you manage to solve?

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by ownership. Make sure the owner and group are correct. In my case:

`# chown -R OWNER:GROUP logs/ httpdocs/ error_docs/`

Answer (score 0):

Give permitions to the project by following this command

```
sudo chmod -R 777 <file>
```

for you it is web so: `sudo chmod -R 777 web`

Answer (score 0):

This is related to a bug in Magento - resolved with SUPEE 11155

app/Mage.php

Change approx line 819

```
$logValidator = new Zend_Validate_File_Extension($_allowedFileExtensions);
$logDir = self::getBaseDir('var') . DS . 'log';
if (!$logValidator->isValid($logDir . DS . $file)) {
    return;
}
```

To

```
$logDir = self::getBaseDir('var') . DS . 'log';
$validatedFileExtension = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if (!$validatedFileExtension || !in_array($validatedFileExtension, $_allowedFileExtensions)) {
    return;
}
```